# Specifying column with multiple datatypes in Spark Schema

Tags: apache-spark, jsonschema, pyspark-schema

I am trying to create schema to parse json into spark dataframe

I have column value in json which could be either struct or string

```
"value": {
    "entity-type": "item",
    "id": "someid",
    "numeric-id": 30
  }

"value": "SomePicture.jpg",
```

How can i specify that in the schema

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "type": ["object", "string"],
  "properties": { ... }
}
```

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html

Comment: In json we can do the way you specified.
But while defining spark schema it doesnt work

So for Spark schema
I had to fetch value in string and then determine if value is going to be of structtype, based on certain conditions and then use
from_json(value, new StructType()) to convert string back to json

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using below approach

In JSON, we can do the way you specified above.
But while defining spark schema it doesn't work
So for Spark schema I had to fetch value in `String` and then determine if value is going to be of structtype, based on certain conditions and then use `from_json(value, new StructType())`
to convert string back to JSON